# Как исправить проблему с сценариями php (работа с .htaccess)?

Tags: php, .htaccess, редирект

.htaccess (это только часть его):
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?key=$1 [L]`

index.php:

```
<?php
$key = $_GET['key'];
    switch ($key) {
        case 'main':
            require_once './main.php';
            break;
        // ...
        default:
            require_once './error404.php';
    }
?>
```

Ситуация такая: если обращаться к несуществующему файлу без перехода по всяким директориям (т.е. если в адресной строке написать http://домен/адрес_несуществующего_файла ), то срабатывает `require_once './error404.php';` , а вот если использовать директории (т.е. http://домен/существующая_директория/адрес_несуществующего_файла), то вылезет ошибка от самого браузера с оповещением, что такой страницы не существует, т.е. `require_once './error404.php';` не срабатывает.

Подскажите, как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте убрать из индекса все папки в корне сайта, добавив запись в `.htaccess`:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Подробней об этом по [ссылке](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/mod/overrides.html#override-indexes)